# Custom queries in JPARepository

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I want to create custom queries in a String variable based on user selections and then i want to insert into @Query and execute it
For example

```
class RequestResource
.
.
String query = "select r from Request r";
requestRepository.test(query);
.
.


class RequestRepository
.
.
@Query("?1")
List<Request> test(String query);
.
.
```

Comment: Be very careful when creating query strings from user input. SQL Injection is a scary thing.  Also, to attract more positive feedback to your question, try adding a specific question.  At the moment, no question has been asked. Explain what problem you're running into, whether it's an error or unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

i think i solve it with this

```
    String finalQuery = "select r from Request r " + leftJoins + " where " + queryParams;
    log.error("QUERY " + finalQuery);
    TypedQuery<Request> query1 = em.createQuery(finalQuery, Request.class);
```